# Can Not Enable To FilleStream

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

I have sql server v2016 on windows server D V2016 .
i can not enable to FileStrem.error Code (0x80041001)

[image: Error Image]

[image: New Image]

Comment: Did you install the 32bit version of SQL server on a 64bit host, by any chance?

Comment: ssms or engine or .... ? Which one version? see new image above

Comment: SSMS <> SQL Server (and SSMS is only available as a 32bit application). If you connect to your instance, what does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: my windows server 2016 64X

Comment: Windows Server 2016 is only available in 64bit. That's why I'm asking about your data engine.

Comment: my sql server 2016 x64

Comment: --Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor) 
--Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Do you get the same error using T-SQL: `EXEC sp_configure 'filestream access level', 2;RECONFIGURE;`? If so, it could be registry permissions. Try toggling the SQL Server service account using SSCM.